# How to display data from database based upon some condition?

Tags: c#

In my database there are 2 tables named talltree_master and talltree_harvest.
I want to display only those records(talltree_id field) that were not harvested from beginning.
For ex. Consider the following data

```
talltree_id |harvest_qty(2009)
1       |   5                 
2       |   0             
3       |   1

talltree_id | harvest_qty(2010) 
1       |    0                   
2       |    0           
3       |    1

talltree_id | harvest_qty(2011) 
1       |    5                   
3       |    6           
4       |    0
```

I want to display only tree_no 2 because it has not been harvested from starting where as tree_no 1 has harvested in 2009 and in 2011 and 4 has been harvested in 2010.

the below code display all the records that are not harvested(Displays tree_no 1,2 and 4) . I don't understand what where condition to include so that i'l get the correct output

```
string query = "select talltree_id from talltree_harvest where harvest_qty=0";
```

Comment: You should use [string builder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx). Your are creating a lot of strings, because every string is immutable and you can't change it.

Comment: It looks like what you're doing will be vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: You have lots of other fields in the query (block_id, area_id, etc.), that you didn't explain to us in your question. Do you really need them for this query to work? If not, rewrite the query so it just uses talltree_id and harvest_qty. Otherwise, explain exactly how each field works.

Comment: You should use Linq instead of tinkering with strings.

Comment: @musical_coder Hello, I have edited the query. please check and provide me the ans, it's bit urgent.

Comment: Actually, Code Uniquely beat me to it :) His answer looks spot on. Just as a rule of thumb for the future, finding a column that meets a certain condition should be relatively simple. So if you find yourself writing a very complicated query like the one you originally had, step back and see if you can simplify it (chances are you can).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the ID's together and then check the SUM of the times harvested is zero.

```
select * from talltree_harvest Group by talltree_id HAVING SUM(harvest_qty) = 0
```